# python) how to import something by variable or by using class

Tags: python, function, class, import

I want to import data one by one  from `sklearn.datasets` and make `dataframe` as below:

```
# load_iris, load_wine, and etc.    
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
s = pd.Series(iris.target, dtype="category")
s = s.cat.rename_categories(iris.target_names)
df['target'] = s
```

based on that code above, I gonna make function as below:

```
def load(data_cmd, key):

    from sklearn.datasets import data_cmd
    key = data_cmd()

    df = pd.DataFrame(key.data, columns=key.feature_names)
    t = pd.Series(key.target, dtype="category")
    t = t.cat.rename_categories(key.target_names)

    return df
```

but I have no idea how to `import` data by variable or keyword.

edit) 
I am not that good at `class`. 
if there is better way, like `class`, implementing what I asked above,
please kindly teach me how to code it :)

Comment: I think you are asking how to import by class rather than variable or keyword. Please edit the question so we can help you out :)

Comment: @KobeThompson OP wants to import dynamically, though I have to admit "by variable or keyword" isn't the best description.

Comment: @exe oh got it, thanks. Actually I don't know well class and wanted to make func instead of it. but if there is better way to code what I asked by class, please help me out ~ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `importlib`:

```
import importlib

def load(data_cmd, key):

    data_method = getattr(importlib.import_module('sklearn.datasets'), data_cmd)
    key = data_method()

    df = pd.DataFrame(key.data, columns=key.feature_names)
    t = pd.Series(key.target, dtype="category")
    t = t.cat.rename_categories(key.target_names)

    return df
```